# Click event is getting triggered twice in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I have a table with two columns named **name** and **attendance** which is a radio button and I want to implement that whenever I click on a row I get the value of name and attendance of that row. The problem is that whenever I clicked on a row the event is triggering twice and showing the name twice. I have added the code below

```
<table class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Attendance</th>

    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-id='1'>
        <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
        <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Present
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" checked>
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Absent
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Following is the jQuery code.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".table_attendance").on('click', function () {
            var attendance = {
              name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have followed other answers related to this problem and added their solution like adding `.off("click")` and

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

But none of these is working and moreover using `.preventDefault()` is disabling the checked option in radio button. Please help me with the code.

Comment: I can see it is working fine for me but I found an error due to selector 'find("td:nthchild(1)")' it should 'find("td:nth-child(1)")'.

Comment: It was a typo. Originally I have 'find("td:nth-child(1)")'. But its not working for me

Comment: what actually do you want with the click on whole td, is there possibility to only click on input. $(".table_attendance input")

Comment: I had the similar issue, in my case it was the script file attached multiple times on the same page.

Comment: adding this two calls  `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update you click event like below:

```
$(".table_attendance").on('click', 'input', function(e) {
```

You can try it below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".table_attendance").on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    var attendance = {
      name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
    };
    console.log(attendance);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">Attendance</th>

  </tr>
  <tr class="" data-id='1'>
    <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
    <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
      <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                               id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        Present
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                               id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" checked>
                        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        Absent
                    </label>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working.Can you explain please why the previous one is not working?

Comment: @TasfiaSharmin You need to go thru this https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Actually it was firing event for click on `label` and `input` both elements. With using `.on('click', 'input'` it will only fire on input is clicked. Ultimately click on label or span will automatically trigger input click so it will work fine.

Comment: @TasfiaSharmin this happens because of event bubbling check my answe below

Answer (score 2):

Just add  input:

Bind the click event to the input rather than the `<td>`. When the  is clicked - the event will still occur because, a click on the `<td>` triggers a click on the input. This will allow the `<td>` to hold its normal functionality.

**Click event Bubbles**, now what is meant by bubbling,

Refer:
[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".table_attendance").on('click','input', function () {
            console.log('clicked');
            var attendance = {
              name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Attendance</th>

    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-id='1'>
        <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
        <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Present
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" checked>
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Absent
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Tasfia this happens because of event bubbling

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".table_attendance input").on('click',function(e) {
    var attendance = {
      name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
    };
    console.log(attendance);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
    <th class="text-center">Attendance</th>

  </tr>
  <tr class="" data-id='1'>
    <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
    <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
      <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                               id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        Present
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
        <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                               id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" checked>
                        <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                        Absent
                    </label>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

This will also work
`$(".table_attendance input")` will select all the input under table_attendance  class.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can also try this one
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".table_attendance input[type='radio']").click( function()
        {

          var attendance = {
          name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
        };
        console.log(attendance);
    });

});
//result {name: "Md. Khairul Basar"}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added `input[name=exampleRadio]:checked` to insure that events should be fire only on click on `name=exampleRadio radio button`

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".table_attendance").on('click','input[name=exampleRadio]:checked', function () {
            var attendance = {
              name: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
            }
                    alert(attendance)
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Attendance</th>

    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-id='1'>
        <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
        <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios1" value="option1">
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Present
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio"
                           id="exampleRadios2" value="option2" checked>
                    <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                    Absent
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change:
<tr class="" data-id='1' id="tr_name_attendance">
change:
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tr_name_attendance").on('click', function () {
            var name = {
                nm: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
            }
            var attendance = {
                attend: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text()
            }
            alert(name.nm);
            alert(attendance.attend);
        });
    });
```